# How to connect FME user attributes from reader to writer when there are transformers in between

Tags: fme-form

I have the following schema (figure) in which a reader takes an excel file and writes something into a database.
In between I have added several transformers. 
For some reason I can not pass the user attributes I need from the reader to the writer (red arrows in the writer).
How can I solve this?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Instruction_Image]

You need to check that your attributes have been passed through the workspace. Click on arrow (1 in the image). This should show your attributes at the featuremerger.

You can then map the attributes across manually by clicking the arrow against the attribute (2 in the image) and then clicking the corresponding arrow at the writer (3 in the image).

Ordinarily, FME will automatically map/link attributes where the names are the same so you could also use the 'attributerenamer' as a more robust solution.

Hope that helps.